# XSLT: Replace special characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to replace "¬"-characters with "-" in strings in a XML file.

This is what I have so far (not working):

```
  <xsl:template name="search-and-replace">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="'&#172;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string" select="//text()"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string" select="'-'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$search-string and contains($input,$search-string)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input,$search-string)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="search-and-replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input,$search-string)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$replace-string"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why can't you use `translate($input, '¬', '-')`?

Comment: Like that?   <xsl:template name="test" match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '¬', '-')"/>
  </xsl:template> Doesn't work.

Comment: Both for you original question and the convoluted code as well as for my suggestion you simply say "it doesn't work" without showing any input you have, any minimal but complete XSLT you apply together with the output and error you get and the result you want. Doing `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., '¬', '-')"/></xsl:template>` together with the identity transformation template should change that character in all text nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear when I stated it's an XML file (nothing special about it). The output was clear for me too, as I just wanted to replace the character mentioned. There never was an error message, the template just didn't do anything. I'm going to be more precise next time, thanks for bringing it up. My fault was that I didn't realize I already have a template matching `text()`. I included the translate function you recommended there and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in XSLT 1, to replace one character by another, the XPath `translate` function can do that job:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '¬', '-')"/>
</xsl:template>
```